# Clustering a number of points with the same coordinate around a central point

Tags: qgis, clustering

Is there a plugin in QGIS to randomly distribute points with the same coordinates around the coordinate? Similar to the "shift point plugin", but instead of producing a circle of points the points are distributed around the coordinate randomly within a set distance or polygon.

Is there a plugin that does this or is there a combination of tools I could use to do this? I have looked online but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: "randomly distribute points with the same coordinates around the coordinate" is not exactly clear